# How to split colors correctly in custom BarLegend?

Tags: plotting, legending

when using a built-in color scheme it splits correctly in the BarLegend, for example

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Now I would like to split this scheme into 3 or 4 main colors, which can be done like this

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, 2]
```

[image]

since we choose to split into 3 colors the new color bar contains the first (violet) and the last(red) color in the original bar and the one in the middle (green). This is not what happens when we use custom schemes like

```
BarLegend[{{Red, Orange, Yellow, White, Green, Blue}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Now, if I want to split into 3 colors it gives

```
BarLegend[{{Red, Orange, Yellow, White, Green, Blue}, {0, 1}}, 2]
```

[image]

Not that it picks the first three colors in the list. I want it to get the first last and the one at the middle like in the `Rainbow`  scheme, how can I let MMA do that automatically?

Comment: `BarLegend[{Blend[{Red, Orange, Yellow, White, Green, Blue}, #] &, {0, 
   1}}, 2]`?

Comment: How can I add ticks in the middle of each color please, tried this but did not work! `BarLegend[{Blend[{Red, Orange, Yellow, White, Green, Blue}, #] &, {0,1}}, 4, Ticks -> {{0.1, "0.2"}, {0.3, "0.4"}, {0.5, "0.6"}, {0.7, 
    "0.8"}, {0.9, "1"}}]`